# Can one transfer pokemon from GBA to DS using different English versions?

Tags: pokemon-ruby-sapphire-emerald, pokemon-diamond-pearl-platinum

I recently tried transfering pokemon from my English (US) version pokemon emerald to my German (Austrian) pokemon platinum. It, of course, did not work, because, as I later found out, one cannot transfer between different versions (English to German in my case). For this reason I am thinking about purchasing an English pokemon platinum version. My question now is, whether it is possible to transfer my pokemon from pokemon emerald (US) to pokemon platinum (British version) or do I need a US version of pokemon platinum to do so? I could unfortunately not find any information regarding this version difference (same language, but cartridge from different countries).

I would really appreciate any information you might have on this topic!

Thank you so much!

Comment: I think, but not entirely sure, it's related to region-locking instead of different languages. Thus I think you can't transfer between US and British. Since you have the two games, you should be able to test this yourself